# Why is my bibliography not working?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, pdftex

This is my `references.bib` file:

```
@article{fakeref,
title = {Fast-swimming sperm causes hurricanes in Africa},
volume = {7},
issn = {1234-5678},
shorttitle = {Sperm and hurricanes},
doi = {12.3456/j.ffs.2050.01.001},
abstract = {Our results suggest that fast-swimming sperm from human males are the main cause of hurricanes on the west coast of Africa.},
language = {eng},
number = {2},
journal = {Journal of Sperm and Climate Change},
author = {Eggnowitz, Eggina and Spermirowski, Sperminald},
month = apr,
year = {2050},
keywords = {Sperm,Hurricanes,Tornados,Eggs,Africa,Climate change,Global warming},
pages = {77--100}
}
```

And this is my MWE (`mwe.tex`):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib} %Bibliography.
\setcitestyle{number} %Cite as numbers or author-year.
\bibliographystyle{vancouver} %Reference style.

\begin{document} %Everything that's written should come next.
\title{\vspace{-1.0cm}\textbf{\Large{This is a title}}} %Title

Random text here \citep{fakeref}.

\bibliography{‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨references}

\end{document}
```

When I run the following:

```
$ pdflatex mwe.tex
```

I get the following terminal output:

```
$ pdflatex mwe.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) 
(./mwe.aux)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `fakeref' on page 1 undefined on input line 16
.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                #4  \errhelp \@err@     
...
l.18 ...{‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨references}

?
```

I have tried many things but nothing seems to make it work. Whenever I include `\bibliography{references}` in the code, it doesn't compile and I get this same error message. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Welcoma to TeX SX! Did you follow the cycle `'pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: Yes, I used the compiling chain. The error happens already in the first pdflatex and stops there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you have hidden letters in your name for bib file `reference.bib`. Please see the following MWE (using your bib file `reference.bib`, be sure it is without hidden letters in the filename too!):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib} %Bibliography.
\setcitestyle{numbers} %Cite as numbers or author-year.
\bibliographystyle{vancouver} %Reference style.


\begin{document} %Everything that's written should come next.
\title{\vspace{-1.0cm}\textbf{\Large{This is a title}}} %Title

Random text here \citep{fakeref}.

%\bibliography{‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨‎⁨references} % <========================================
\bibliography{references} % <===========================================

\end{document}
```

In the commented line with command `\bibliography` you can find the hidden letters. On my editor I can see the hidden letters like:

[image: hidden letters]

Compiling the code (and using `numbers` in `\setcitestyle`) I get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
\setcitestyle{numbers}
```

instead of

```
\setcitestyle{number}
```

Edit:

section 2.9 in the `natbib` documentation says, the citation mode is `numbers`, as mentioned in the reference sheet.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't know why, but it works when I type \bibliography{references} instead of copying it from your MWE. I get errors when I copy that line.

Comment: @Bart maybe the answer to why your answer works lies in the manual. you should research it and add it as justification to your answer.

Comment: @Kurt solved the problem. For some reason, there are hidden characters in my code.